# Веб приложение, Spring, долгая операция, как выводить информацию на странице?

Tags: spring

Есть операция, которая делается примерно 30мин и примерно каждые 30 сек эта операция может записывать сообщения о ходе выполнения. Как мне на веб странице выводить эти сообщения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете запустить эту операцию в новом треде, чтоб соединение с клиентом не упало по таймауту. Пока задача выполняется, сохраняйте в базу / кешируйте информацию о прогрессе. Клиент каждые n секунд может делать запросы на бэкенд, чтоб эту информацию получить.

Для больших операций может быть удобно использовать Spring Batch.

Comment: String Batch или Spring Batch?

Comment: Spring, прошу прощения)